# yield example in Dart

Tags: functional-programming, dart

How to use yield in Dart as a same as Scala? 
There is an example in Scala "https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-for-loop-yield-examples-yield-tutorial"

```
scala> val a = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
a: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> for (e <- a if e > 2) yield e
res1: Array[Int] = Array(3, 4, 5)
```

How can I do it in dart?

```
void main() {
  var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  for (var e in a) {
    if (e > 2) yield e;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't care about Scala. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: How good is Dart's support for functional programming.

Comment: That's not really a question for StackOverflow. Darts functional support is good but there are better languages for functional programming, if that is any help ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `for (e <- a if e > 2) yield e` expression is an [*expression*](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/for-comprehensions.html) in Scala.
It evaluates to an array. Dart does not have that as a direct expression, but you can make functions that return iterables in much the same way, and then call them immediately to create an expression:

```dart
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
var res = () sync* { for (var v in a) if (v > 2) yield v; } ();
```

Here I introduce a function `() sync* { for (var v in a) if (v > 2) yield v; }` and calls it immediately. That function returns an `Iterable`. The elements of that iterable are the values `yield`'ed by the body, in this case 3, 4 and 5.

Answer (score 10):

Dart and JavaScript has the async/await mechanism.

The function that is asynchronously yielding values, is an async function that returns Stream

```
Stream<int> str() async* {
  // The keyword `async*` means a "generator function" that generates a stream
  List<int> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  for (var e in a) {
    if (e > 2) yield e;
  }
}

main() async {
  await for (var e in str()) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use yielding values without async/await mechanism?

Comment: You can yield with `sync *` to create an `Iterable`